C#: how to create a custom type that can be a Dictionary or a List of Dictionaries
I am trying to create a custom type. Variables which are this type may be either a Dictionary, or a list of Dictionaries
This is how I would create the type using python (using mypy)
CustomType = Union[Dict[str, any], List[Dict[str, any]]]

This is how I would create the type using typescript
type CustomType = object[] | object;

I am wondering how to do the same thing in C#

Not as a first-class language feature, no. You'll need library support. There are various functional programming libraries that provide discriminated union types. You'll have to try them out to see what works best for you.

There is no support for type unions in C#. You can look here for an approximation, but there will always be drawbacks and imperfections because it is not a compiler supported feature.

What is your use case? You could create a class that is capable of holding one of those two types. It would look like a List<Dictionary<string, T>> internally. It would also have a flag describing which type it was playing the role of. It could support two different collection initialization and enumeration syntaxes/semantics. If it was set to a dictionary, it would just expose the first item in the list. You could probably get it working in about an hour; though writing good tests would take longer than writing the code. As an experienced C# programmer, I don't see the benefit in this
